# Postman variables are undefined

Tags: postman

I've just created an account and am using web.postman.co.  The online version.  I didn't actually notice if the desktop client is still available

In my Postman workspace I've created an environment and there I've created a bunch of variables to match my vendor API auth request (Wialon).  The values are pasted below:

```
 [{"key":"hostname","value":"some.address","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"some.address","sessionIndex":0},          
 {"key":"auth_username","value":"wialon","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"wialon","sessionIndex":1},     
 {"key":"auth_password","value":"abc123!","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"abc123","sessionIndex":2},     
 {"key":"auth_token_duration","value":"2592000","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"2592000","sessionIndex":3},
 {"key":"auth_client_id","value":"wialon","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"wialon","sessionIndex":4},
 {"key":"auth_redirect_uri","value":"login.html","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"login.html","sessionIndex":5},
 {"key":"auth_response_type","value":"token","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"token","sessionIndex":6},
 {"key":"auth_access_type","value":"0x200","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"0x200","sessionIndex":7},
 {"key":"auth_activation_time","value":"0","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"0","sessionIndex":8},
 {"key":"auth_flags","value":"0x2","enabled":true,"sessionValue":"0x2","sessionIndex":9}]
```

I've then added a collection which currently has one action `Get - Login`.  This action is pointing at the Environment created earlier.  I can see it in the left of the document bar.  The URL is as follows:

```
http://{{hostname}}/login.html?client_id={{auth_client_id}}&access_type={{auth_access_type}}&activation_time={{auth_activation_time}}&duration={{auth_token_duration}}&lang=en&flags={{auth_flags}}&user={{auth_username}}&redirect_uri={{auth_redirect_uri}}&response_type={{auth_response_type}}&css_url
```

The first error I get, and the most confusing for a new user is

```
GET https://undefined/get?client_id=undefined&access_type=0x200&activation_time=0&duration=undefined&lang=en&flags=0x1&user=wialon&redirect_uri=login.html&response_type=token
Error: DNSLookup: ENOTFOUND undefined
```

Most of the variables are undefined.  This causes the DNS error, but there's no explanation of why they are not defined.  They're clearly set in the environment pane and when hovering over in the action parameters.

The second error, and probably related is:

```
JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Error: DNSLookup: ENOTFOUND undefined
```

This is probably due to the word undefined starting with a 'u'

Why are my variables undefined?  How do I fix it?

**edit:** Requested screenshots

**Action page**
[image: action page]

**Environment Page**
[image: environment variable page]

**Post run errors**
[image: post run errors]

**Edit:** Additional testing

I cloned the action and removed all variable references, hardcoding values in the properties page.  Running this gave back the same undefined errors.

After that I tried copying the URL and placing it in the browser address bar.  This worked.  There was a manual prompt to enter a password, but the url after that returned the `access_token` as described.  Here is [the API ref](https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/local/remoteapi2104/apiref/login/login)

Comment: Do you mind including screenshots of `They're clearly set in the environment pane.`?

Comment: Is the environment also saved or just added? Are the values in the initial and current fields? Do you have the environment set when making the request?

Comment: @Luke I’ll add screenshots tomorrow

Comment: @DannyDainton the environment is specified in the top left, down one.  Same row as the open documents.  All changes are saved.  There are values in initial and current, as seen in the paste from the environment tab

Comment: Without actually seeing the current state - The information above only tells part of what's happening here.

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: It seems there is an error in Pre-request script, then postman doesn't replace `{{variable}}` with actual value --> `{{hostname}}` is still `undefined`

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I thought that was deleted :/  Unlike the actions, the pre request script doesn’t have a save button.